# Why the R version is different in Console and the Terminal

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio

I opening RStudio server,but the R version is 3.4.4 in Console, the R version is 3.6.1 in Terminal. how to updata the R version in Console?

```
in Console:
> if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
+     install.packages("BiocManager")
Installing package into ‘/home/jack/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘BiocManager’ is not available (for **R version 3.4.4**)
Error in readRDS(pfile) : 
  cannot read workspace version 3 written by R 3.6.1; need R 3.5.0 or newer


in Terminal:
(base) jack@omnisky:~$ R

R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes"
Copyright (C) 2019 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?(>▽<)

Comment: See "Specifying R version" in the RStudio server manual: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552316-Configuring-the-Server Have you restarted the RStudio server after upgrading R?

Comment: I restart the Rstudio, it works,thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Execute this command in terminal ：`rstudio-server restart`
Thank you for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

As I do not have enough reputation to comment, I'll write it here:

My hypothesis would be that the R installation used in Rstudio is different than the one installed in your system (Terminal).

Therefore, as @jogo suggested, you should try to check where your 'main R' is installed, and select/paste that path in RStudio (Tools -> options -> General).